# Python CNN Accuracy improvement and Equal weighting of classes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have started programming and have the following problem. I have 35 classes of different sizes that I would like to weight equally. Now I have tested my code and tried different ways to optimise the accuracy, but I never get further than 10 percent. What error am I missing?

```
img_width=256; img_height=256
batch_size=16

TRAINING_DIR = '…'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255.0,
                                   rotation_range=30,
                                   zoom_range=0.4,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
                                                    batch_size=batch_size,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    target_size=(img_height, img_width))

VALIDATION_DIR = '…'

validation_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255.0)

validation_generator = validation_data.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                                              target_size=(img_height, img_width)
                                                             )

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', 
    input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)), 
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'), 
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(35, activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              epochs=30,
                              verbose=1,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              callbacks = [best_model]
                              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes of different sizes means imbalanced set. 35 classes is a lot of classes and accuracy metric would not give  good insight.
You could try look at confusion matrix  to get see how classes are getting miss classified.